# How to get the selected value as name instead of ID in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#

I have the below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SetAllCountries();        
        loadInvoiceDetails();
        if (lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "U.A.E" || lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "BAHRAIN" || lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "SAUDI ARABIA")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}


 private void loadInvoiceDetails()
 {
     ...........
     ..........
     string queryStrLoadInq = "SELECT COMPANY,COUNTRY,EMAIL,CONTACT_NAME FROM  CRM_INQUIRY_PERTICIPANT WHERE INQUIRY_ID=" + currInquiryId + " ";           
     ClassDtBaseConnect clsDtResult = new ClassDtBaseConnect();
     DataTable dtInquiry = clsDtResult.GetDataTable(queryStrLoadInq);
     lstCountryy.SelectedValue = dtInquiry.Rows[0]  ["country"].ToString();//Selected value:18(country id)
}



 protected void SetAllCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            string queryStrUserType = "SELECT country_id,country_name FROM  crm_countries";
            ClassDtBaseConnect clsDtResult = new ClassDtBaseConnect();
            DataTable dt = clsDtResult.GetDataTable(queryStrUserType);
            lstCountryy.DataSource = dt;
            lstCountryy.DataValueField = "country_id";
            lstCountryy.DataTextField = "country_name";
            lstCountryy.DataBind();
            lstCountryy.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

`lstcountryy` is my dropdownlist. So I am getting the selected value as country's id. Instead of that I want country's name. After execution, I am getting the country's name.

I want country's name(selected value) in code also. I tried using `lstcountryy.selecteditem.text` but I dint got the country's name.

There are 2 tables : inquiry table contains countryid and country table contains countryid and name.

I have just started learning C#.

Comment: I think you have some problems in your design that include your database. but  you can change your approach and fill all values  that you need to a view or a fake table and then use it.

Comment: please show how you filling the dropdownlist

Comment: @HeribertoLugo..ya..i have just updated it

Comment: what you get when you tried `lstcountryy.selecteditem.text `

Comment: and did you tried this `lstCountryy.SelectedValue = dtInquiry.Rows[1]["country"].ToString();`

Comment: If it is VB.Net and you are using combobox, **lstcountryy.text** will give the text value of the selected index. I believe that the approach will be similar in C#

Comment: @ashik...i get id of the country only...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SelectedItem` property to get text of selected item.

```
var text = lstCountryy.SelectedItem.Text;
if (text == "U.A.E" || text == "BAHRAIN" || text == "SAUDI ARABIA")
{

}
```

Also, I think, you should change your approach. It is a very fragile code. You could store the special countries in the database.

Comment: I told him that he has problem in database . I think he needs to good design and then he can use it. finally, it's maybe your code work .... but it isn't good way to him.